# Future isn't a type. Try correcting the name to match an existing type.dartnot_a_type

Tags: flutter, types

> Future isn't a type. Try correcting the name to match an existing
> type.dartnot_a_type

I was using sqflite in flutter, here is my code to insert the value into table, where I am getting this error:

```
Future<List<Map<String,dynamic>>> getNoteMapList() async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    var result = await db.query(noteTable, orderBy: '$colPriority ASC');
    return result;
}
```

Comment: does `import 'dart:async'` help?

Comment: For me, closing and re-opening Android Studio helped.

Comment: I had an Error String is not a type. Restarting visual studio helped me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to check your code first.

There's a fairly high probability that you have an extra chevron `>` somewhere in your code  (in that file, but not necessarily on the same line)

*something like*

```dart
Future<Type>> // Notice the extra `>` ‍♂️
```

...and that tricks the linter to believe `Future` is probably a method or something.

The local scope of `Future` in this case takes precedence over whatever is in `dart:async`, so an import might not help.

---

Probable solution:
Look for a trailing `>` and eliminate it.

*like*

```dart
Future<Type> // Extra `>` removed
```

If you can't find a trailing `>`, you've probably got a different issue from what I just described.

Good luck debugging your issue

Comment: Great answer.  For me it happened because I defined my function without giving it a name.  

GIVES THIS ERROR: `List<otherType>(paramType param) { List<otherType> returnVal; ..`  

WORKS: `List<otherType> funcName(paramType param) { List<otherType> returnVal; ..`

Answer (score 7):

*I encountered the same error in VS Code, despite not having forgotten any "<" or ">" characters in the file. This was the first time I had seen this error in four months, since the last time I edited the file.*

Fortunately, **closing and restarting VS Code resolved the issue**.